# Access to JSON objects in auto-complete

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

I have this code:

```
<s:hidden id="s" value="%{Users}"/>
```

`Users` is an array list of User objects. I wrote this code in Javascript. Accessing Users as JSON, I want to show in auto-complete:

```
var values = document.getElementById('s').value;
var availableTags= values.split(",");
```

Change to this:

```
var values = document.getElementById('s').value;
var availableTags= JSON.parse(values);
```

But I don't know what I do to change in the source.

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  response(
    $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
      availableTags, extractLast(request.term)
    )
  );
},
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, it should go a little something like this:

```
// assuming your JSON look somewhat like this [{name: "Jon"}, {name: "Smith"}]
var availableTags = JSON.parse(values).map(function(user){ 
  return user.name; 
}); // return an array of users ["Jon", "Smith"]
```